# Derivative of $\arctan \sqrt x$

Tags: derivatives

The derivative of $\arctan \sqrt x$ is

\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{2\sqrt x(1+x)}
\end{equation}

or

\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{2\sqrt x(1+|x|)}
\end{equation}?

Comment: These coincide where they are both defined.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For $\sqrt{x}$ to be defined, we need $x\geq 0$. So $x = \lvert x \rvert$, and both terms are the same.